# How to set data view of a Column on Print Datatables using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Heres my Scenario:
my DataTable has view like this:
[click to see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtyF7.png)

But when I print it shows like this:
[click to see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LzNR.png)

i want to print like the same in the Datatable(1st pic). How to do that in jquery?

my javascript code is:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#example').DataTable( {
          dom: 'Bfrtip',
           buttons: [
              {
                extend:'print',
                exportOptions:{
                        columns:[
                              0,1,2,3,4
                                ]
                      } 
              }
          ]
      } );
  } );

</script>
```

heres my html/php code:

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="example" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Location Address</th>
              <th>Contact</th>
              <th>Pending Docs</th>
              <th>Status</th>
              <th>Edit</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Location</th>
              <th>Contact</th>
              <th>Pending Docs</th>
              <th>Status</th>
              <th>Edit</th>
            </tr>
          </tfoot>
          <tbody>
            <?php 
              if($fetch_data->num_rows() > 0)
              {
                  foreach($fetch_data->result() as $row)
                  {
                    /*$data["fetch_data"] = $this->main_model->fetch_data();*/

                    $this->load->model("main_model");

                    $docs= $this->main_model->docs_showing($row->cust_id); 
            ?>
                    <tr>
                      <td><?php echo $row->business_name; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row->business_location; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row->cust_contact; ?></td>
                      <td>
                      <?php
                        if($docs->num_rows() > 0)
                        { 
                            echo '<ul>';
                            foreach($docs->result() as $row1)
                            {
                              echo '<li>'.$row1->doc_name.'</li>';
                            }
                            echo '</ul>';
                      ?>  
                      </td>
                      <td>
                      <?php
                            echo '<ul>';
                           foreach($docs->result() as $row1)
                            {
                              echo '<li>'.$row1->doc_status.'</li>';
                            }
                            echo '</ul>';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                          echo "No Docs available";
                        }
                      ?>
                      </td>
                      <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"> Edit</td>
                    </tr>
            <?php
                  }
              }
              else
              {
            ?>

            <?php
              }
            ?>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

what i have to write in javascript code to cutomize the data view in the column on Print functionality ?

Comment: can you add code/more info here?

Comment: i have added. see